# Get Total amount & Quantity for same ID

Tags: laravel

Good Afternoon...
I wanted to get the data from database which will be groupby `customerID` and base on same data in below format :

| customerID | From date | to Date | Total Quantity | Total Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

Refer attached images for my database.
I able to get data `groupby customerID` but stuck for futher details.

```
$test = Dairyincome::get()->groupBy('customerID')->toArray();
dump($test);
```

Expected result

| customerID | From date | to Date | Total Quantity | Total Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Cust-01 | 2022-02-10 | 2022-02-11 | (10+2.3)=12.30 | (450+98.90)=548.90 |

same for other ID

Hope i explained my problem and thanks in Advance[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't recommend using collection (you use `->groupBy()` after `->get()`).

You need to know how it can work using SQL first, before using Eloquent or the Query Builder.

I assume your table is `dairyincomes` :

```
SELECT
  customerID, 
  MIN(date) as "From date", 
  MAX(date) as "To Date",
  SUM(quantity) as "Total Quantity",
  SUM(amount) as "Total Amount"
FROM
  dairyincomes
GROUP BY
  customerID
```

- The `MIN()` function returns the minimum value in a set of values.
- The `MAX()` function returns the maximum value in a set of values.
- The `SUM()` function is an aggregate function that allows you to calculate the sum of values in a set.

Eloquent :

```
Dairyincome::selectRaw('customerID, MIN(date) as "From date", MAX(date) as "To Date", SUM(quantity) as "Total Quantity", SUM(amount) as "Total Amount"')
    ->groupBy('customerID')
    ->get();
```

Also, you can use `DB::raw()` btw.

Reference :

- https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries

Comment: got error = Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SUM(amount) as "Total Amount" from `dairyincomes` group by `customerID`' at line 1 (SQL: select customerID, MIN(date) as "From date", MAX(date) as "To Date", SUM(quantity) as "Total Quantity" SUM(amount) as "Total Amount" from `dairyincomes` group by `customerID`)

Comment: @RahulW sorry forget `,` after `sum`. Updated. Please check.

Comment: Just one more point, if i add customername also, it again giving the error. i tried to add ( 'customerID ,customername, --------')

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: Actually i solve the same... I added "customername " in selectRaw and groupBY. Thanks